# Fast hash function for set equality

Tags: data-structures, sets, hash

I'm searching an hash function for integer set equality that must be fast.
It must support update (adding an element already in the set must not change the hash) and union.
MinHash has these 2 properties but it is too expensive and I do not need all the feature of MinHash, in fact I don't need set similarity but only equality.
Do you know something that can satisfy my needs?
Thanks :)

P.S. I have to implement it in C for an high performance software

Comment: How do you represent a set? Adding a value that is already present doesn’t change the set, so why would it change the hash?

Comment: I do not represent the set, this is the problem. For each new item (an int16_t) I call hash.update(item). I am considering a bloom filter but it seems to expensive in space.

Comment: The answer depends very much on the nature of the integer sets you will encounter. It would be nice if you can share a few hundreds or more such such sets.

Comment: Is "adding a new item" the only modifying operation on the set?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I really don't see how adding a few hundred examples to the question would help. That's an absurd amount of data to demand: it could be a huge amount of work for the asker and I don't see how it would be useful to most answerers.

Comment: What does "update" mean? You say that adding an element to the set shouldn't modify the hash, but that doesn't tell us whether adding an element is the only update operation you need to support.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It takes less than a minute for me to share data of a few megabytes somewhere on the internet. I agreed and agree that it could be a huge amount of work for the asker, though.

Comment: @DavidRicherby XY problems pop up from time to time. The description in the answer is not as clear as we would like. Asking for concrete examples is one of my standard responses. Hopefully, it could be useful for other answerers.

Comment: @AndreaFioraldi Have you tried the sum of all numbers? Or the sum of each number multiplied by some varying power of 2?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Sum of the numbers doesn't work: if you add $x$ to the set twice, the hash gets incremented twice, but it should only get incremented once.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks, I missed the operation that "adds an element already in the set".

Answer (score 3):

MinHash already *is* super-fast.  I suggest you check whether you understand correctly how MinHash works.

Take any standard hash function $H$; then all you have to do is compute $H$ once on each element of the set.  You can implement $H$ with as fast a hash algorithm as you want.  The update operation requires one call to $H$ (namely, if your set's hash is currently $y$, and you add element $x$, the new hash is $\min(y, H(x))$), and the union operation is super fast (namely, the union of two sets with hashes $y_1,y_2$ is $\min(y_1,y_2)$).  Notice that these operation have the property you want (adding an element already in the set does not change the hash).

I have a hard time imagining how you could get much faster than that.

If you want this to be faster, a reasonable way is to choose a $H$ that is faster.

I've described a variant where the hash of a set is the smallest of the element-hashes.  The only downside is that the number of hash collisions might higher than you like.  Measure and see if that is actually a problem in practice.  If it is, you can consider variants that keep the $k$ distinct smallest element hashes.  If $k$ is large, you can store those $k$ hashes in a heap of size $k$ to make the update and union operations faster.